# Shift to the right elements of the vector

Tags: c

The user enter a sequence of N numbers saved in a vector. The program first does a shift to the left of vector elements and assigns 0 to the last element. Then it does a shift to the right of the new vector elements and assigns 0 to the first element.

Problem: I can't do correctly the shift to the right 'cause the output is wrong, but I don't understand what mistake I made. See `//SHIFT TO THE RIGHT//` and `vet[0]=0`.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int maxn=300; //max vector dimension
    int N; //vector dimension
    int vet[maxn]; 
    int i; //index

    do 
    {
        printf("how many numbers will be entered?");
        scanf("%d", &N);

        if (N>maxn || N<=0)
        {
            printf("ERROR.The number must be between 0 and %d\n", maxn);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    while (N>maxn || N<=0);

    printf("Enter a sequence of %d numbers\n", N);
    printf("\n");

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("element number %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("the sequence entered is:\n");
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", vet[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");


    //SHIFT TO THE LEFT//
    //1 2 3 4 -> 2 3 4 0//

    for(i=0; i<N-1; i++)
    {
        vet[i]=vet[i+1];
    }
    vet[N-1]=0;


    printf("The resulting sequence from the shift to the left is:\n");
    printf("\n");

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", vet[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //SHIFT TO THE RIGHT//
    // 2 3 4 0 -> 0 2 3 4//
    for (i=N-1; i>0; i--);
    {
        vet[i]=vet[i-1];
    }
    vet[0]=0;


    printf("The resulting sequence from the shift to the right is: \n");
    printf("\n");

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", vet[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Too much code.  I'd advise you to decompose the problem into small, easy to test functions.  Don't worry about all that I/O noise.  Get the shift to work with an array you hardwire and pass.  Can you write a function that takes in an array and returns an array?  Start with that.

Comment: `for (i=N-1; i>0; i--);`  ← semi-colon.

Comment: Thanks. The mistake is in for cicle, changing i=N-1 in i=N (line 62) the output is right.

Comment: No, that will access a bad index. Just removing the semi-colon works: https://ideone.com/67ihpL. Your solution seems to work because the array is much larger than it needs to be. However, if the array were exactly the right size (where `N == maxn`), `vet[N]` would be wrong.